# GIT VCS not updating sources after Teamcity upgrade

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-8.0, teamcity-9.0

I have recently upgraded to Teamcity 9 from 8. Ever since the upgrade, all of my GIT VCS are not updating sources. Build log show below but the checkout directory is empty.

```
[04:33:49]Using vcs information from agent file: 53c2fd4d_Test.Project.xml
[04:33:49]Clean build enabled: removing old files from D:\Builds\Test.Project
[04:33:49]Checkout directory: D:\Builds\Test.Project
[04:33:49]Updating sources: server side checkout
[04:33:49][Updating sources] Will perform clean checkout. Reason: "Clean all files before build" turned on
[04:33:49][Updating sources] Transferring cached clean patch for VCS root: Test Project
[04:33:49][Updating sources] Repository sources transferred
[04:33:49][Updating sources] Removing D:\Builds\Test.Project
```

I tried cleaning Server cache at `<TeamCity Data Directory>/system/caches` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. 
For a while the `refs/heads/<BranchName>` `<HASH>` we saw in the changes tab for any build would point back to a commit from a time when upgraded from 8 to 9. Stubbornly ignoring any subsequent checkins.

The cause for us *may* have been running out of licensed users within Stash. But there was no sign of any error from git/stash/swabra in any TeamCity logs we looked at.
That stash licencing issue was fixed by one part of our organization while at the same time we:

- checked `on` the `Enable to use tags in the branch specification` in the VcsRoot specification. (We don't actually use Tags, and our branch specification patterns would never match with tags in our stash/git repo.)
- At this point, the web ui seems to *show* some quite crazy change sets. For a branch build X we saw commits from unrelated branches. However the code built was probably actually correct. And every branch ever seen by TeamCity wanted to re-build.
- bounced the TeamCity Server.
- checked `off`, then `on` again,  'Enable to use tags in the branch specification’.

Then we seem to get the correct change sets in the web UI.
Surely some of those steps are redundant. But that's what worked for us.

Comment: Well what worked for me was deleting and re-creating the VCS root.

Comment: Re-creating the VCS helped me as well.